# I should be able to wear more than one hat

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

**NOT TRIVIAL**

By hat, I mean all items in the Winter Bash (hats, goggles, etc). Why can't I wear more than one? I know it's a little awkward to wear two hats but why can't I wear a hat and a pair of goggles at least?

Comment: I mean, I’d like this feature too, but it is, in fact, trivial.

Comment: [Hah! Tarnish notte the majesty of my TOWER of HATS.](http://www.teamfortress.com/classless/hidden/hats/)

Comment: I stopped wearing my hats because of Black Mirror.

Comment: Maybe because [it gets crazy after a while](https://ashleylange.deviantart.com/art/Every-Hat-In-TF2-401600741)

Comment: @Machavity I am dizzy from that :-)

Comment: And I just learned you can actually do something with these hats. I just thought they were fun little achievements that would go away. Nothing in the "You've just earned" dialog suggests that you do anything with the hat (like maybe a "Wear" button, or a "change hat" link near the top.) Sure, once I knew it was a feature, it was trivial to figure out how, but it wasn't discoverable in the first place.

Comment: Yes, if ordinary letters can have a tower of hats ( like this ô̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂), then why can't avatars? Besides, didn't they do this a couple of years ago, that one of the achievements you could earn was the ability to wear multiple hats?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Because the system doesn't support it, see [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159320/295232) by a user who was a Stack Exchange employee back then:

> Sorry, I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this idea just because layering that many images on a gravatar isn't really feasible for us -- not without severely sacrificing performance.
>
> That said, there's a fairly easy "cheat" around this -- just screencap your gravatar wearing a hat, make that image your gravatar, and equip a different hat. repeat until you are wearing all the hats! (If you do this, I suggest using the version of profile page!)

Comment: Wow, awesome. I'll try this out!

Comment: Travis J [demonstrates this workaround](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1026459/travis-j). Bonus: it's permanent.

Comment: Although it is obviously why this feature will not be implemented it is still clear that creating a screen shot with all hats you want on your gravatar will not the same thing as having *real* hats on it: true hats can be placed beyond of gravatar's edges  :(

Answer (score 7):

You can fake it, simply just take a screenshot of your profile logo wit the first hat, then save as a image, then set that for your profile picture, then simply wear another hat on the site, then you can have two hats, you can even go further.

That really just "cheating" and "faking" stuff, some users do that, example this user:

*https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275490/vickel*

Comment: I'd call it "creativity" :)

Comment: @Vickel Lol, funny :-)